# How to access Fields property/class

Tags: core-service

I'm new to Tridion and trying to update a component's metadata field from Core Service API through .Net code and got to know the following article:

https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/ChangeContentOrMetadata

I'm wondering how to get the Fields property/class in my project. Could you please shed some light on it?

```
// load the schema
var schemaFields = client.ReadSchemaFields(SCHEMA_URI, true, DEFAULT_READ_OPTIONS);

// load a component based on that schema
var component = (ComponentData)client.Read(COMPONENT_URI, DEFAULT_READ_OPTIONS);
Console.WriteLine(component.Content);

// build a magical Fields object from it
var fields = Fields.ForContentOf(schemaFields, component);

// let's first quickly list all values of all fields
foreach (var field in fields)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} (Type={1})", field.Name, field.Type));
    foreach (var value in field.Values)
    {
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + value);
    }
}
```

Comment: any luck Anthony?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download/copy source code from following class and include it in your project.

[Field Class](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/source/browse/ChangeContentOrMetadata/CreateContentOrMetadata/CreateContentOrMetadata.cs)

Comment: @Antony: I will suggest to Google/search SE before posting such small issues on this forum. this link was part of article you shared.

Comment: Indeed i did a round of search in Google and stack exchange before raising my question here. Anyways, i overlooked at the article.

Comment: Worth noting that this repo has now moved and the source is now here: https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/blob/master/ChangeContentOrMetadata/CreateContentOrMetadata/CreateContentOrMetadata.cs